# Convert dataframe column from Object to float or int

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert the dtype of several dataframe columns from the default when read in from CSV:

```
DF = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1',
    usecols = ['Email ID','Total CTC'], dayfirst = True, parse_dates=True)

DF.dtypes

Email ID       object
GDOJ           object
Total CTC      object
dtype: object
```

1. trying to convert `Total CTC` to `float` :-

```
DF['Total CTC'] = DF['Total CTC'].astype(float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '69,608.00'
```

2. trying to convert `Total CTC` to `int` :-

```
DF['Total CTC'] = DF['Total CTC'].astype(int)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '69,608.00'
```

3. `HR['Total CTC'].apply(lambda x:x.dtype)`

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dtype'`

please suggest solution.

I want create one new column with multiply this column and another column where value is 5

Comment: Please use proper code formatting

Comment: unable to understand, could you please format the code

Comment: How the values look like for example in Total CTC column? Some sample data would be nice to see.

Comment: Also, everyone please be sure to tag [tag:pandas]. This is so dupes and related questions get suggested, expert users get shown this question etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the column like this :

```
DF['Total CTC'] = DF['Total CTC'].str.replace(',' ,'').astype(float)
```

Comment: Isn't it this str.replace(',', ".").astype(float)?? (missing dot)